# $1$ heap of sand $+\ 1$ heap of sand $= 1$ heap of sand?

Tags: philosophy, paradoxes

My uncle, who barely passed elementary school math (which leads me to believe he read this in some kind of joke magazine), once told me this when I was very young.

$$1 \text{ heap of sand } + 1\text{ heap of sand } = 1\text{ heap of sand}
.$$

It does sound like a joke, but as I learned more and more math (still at basic college math), I still couldn't (and can't) disprove/prove it.

So we all know this is true "linguistically," since if you add 1 heap of sand to another one, it will still be a heap of sand, but mathematically, 1 + 1 cannot equal 1.

I expect there to be, and wouldn't be surprised if there weren't, similar questions to this one but I couldn't find it using the search feature.

I guess I'm going out on a limb here because of the stupidity (and perhaps the obvious answer) of this question, but I seriously cannot disprove this based on what I know.

Comment: This is known as the [Sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox).

Comment: @LucaBressan Not exactly. The only resemblance is there is a heap of sand involved.

Comment: Similar concept to $o(x)+o(x)=o(x)$, which works because you only add it finitely many times

Comment: The question is whether the mathematical structure of natural numbers and their addition is applicable. In particular, is "bring $A$ and $B$ together and mix them" justifiably represented by ""$+$"?

Comment: @LucaBressan I read about that one, but it's not exactly the same.

Comment: I do not see what there is to prove or disprove here. You state two obvious facts:

 1. Two heaps of sand put together make a heap of sand.
 2. $1+1\neq1$. I'll assume this to be about (natural, whole or real) numbers.

What makes you believe there is any relation between these two statements?

Comment: @Servaes Well that's what I'm trying to figure out. There seems to be a relation, but at the same time, it doesn't.

Comment: I do not see any relation between the two, nor any reason to believe that there is. That's why I asked: *What makes you believe* that there is any relation between the two?

Comment: The real problem is with the definition of addition here.  If addition means the heaps of sand are not changed in any way, then 1 heap + 1 heap = 2 heaps. If on the other hand it means they are combined, then 1 heap + 1 heap = 1 heap.

Comment: For this to be an actual mathematical problem, first you need to *define* what does a "heap of sand" mean.

Comment: Ok, so based on the answers I've gotten so far, this seems to not be a mathematical problem unless I define a "heap of sand". I completely agree (based on everything that seems logical). However, if it's not mathematical, what kind of problem is it? What happens if we choose not to define a "heap of sand"? Just a side thought that sprung out of these answers.

Comment: Reminds me of this SMBC comic: http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/heap-problems

Comment: What's your definitions of "$1$", "heap of sand" and "$+$"?

Answer (score 12):

The resolution here is that $+$ does not refer to addition, but to composition, or more mathematically union of sets. The "1" here does not refer to the coefficient alongside the unit "heap of sand", neither is "heap of sand" actually a unit. The "1" is actually just a standin for an indefinite article.

So a mathematical model of your uncle's statement goes something like this:

> The union of a set of sand and a set of sand is a set of sand.

More formally:

> For any $A, B \subset S$, $A \cup B \subset S$.

Clearly this is a completely different statement than $1 + 1 = 1$.

Comment: Interesting, so set theory is the way to answer this question?

Comment: @Lobs002, yes, it looks to be better one

Comment: @GCab it is, the heap being obviously in this context an alias of set

Comment: @igael or a subset of the set "Sand" ?

Answer (score 3):

One thing you must notice here is that:

> $$1\, \text{heap of sand} + 1\, \text{heap of sand} = 1\, \text{heap
>  of sand} \not \large\Rightarrow 1+1=1$$

The reason is that $1$ heap is *not well-defined or quantitative or mathematical enough* for being used to perform mathematical operations like addition,subtraction and **make equations**. If you had mentioned $1$ Kg. or perhaps $1$ quintal or even, in some special case, $1$ bag of sand, then also you can perform addition,subtraction etc. and equate both sides of the "$=$" sign. Otherwise this equation makes no sense.

It is similarly *wrong* to say that $$1\, \text{straight line} + 1\, \text{straight line} = 1\, \text{straight line} \implies 1+1=1$$

Instead as pointed out by McFry, you should try to use set theory to clarify your problem since it is a clear case of *composition*.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, there is nothing wrong with the statement,
$$
1\text{ heap of sand} + 1\text{ heap of sand} = 1\text{ heap of sand}.
$$
For example, in the extended real numbers, $\infty + \infty = \infty$.
This does *not* imply $1 + 1 = 2$ on its own.

However, I think you have understood your uncle's statement wrong in writing it down that way. A better way to write it down mathematically -- one that seems more true to the meaning -- is to say,
$$
\text{If } x \text{ and } y \text{ are heaps of sand, then } x + y \text{ is a heap of sand}.
$$

Now if we define a "heap of sand" to be a natural number which has size at least $1000$ (representing the number of grains of sand), then we are simply saying that two natural numbers which have size at least $1000$ add to a natural number of size at least $1000$. Which is perfectly true and correct.

Finally, I must comment on:

> I still couldn't (and can't) disprove/prove it.

You couldn't prove or disprove it because it's *not a mathematical statement* until you define what a "heap of sand" is, and what it means to add two of them. That is the crux of the problem here. Start out by defining what a "heap of sand" is, and then we may be able to see if the statement is correct or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does seem like it pretty much perfectly answers my question. I'll wait a few hours and sees if anyone disagrees.

Comment: The bigger problem is with the definition of addition here; not the definition of "heap of sand."  If addition means the heaps of sand are not changed in any way, then 1 heap + 1 heap = 2 heaps.  If on the other hand it means they are combined, then 1 heap + 1 heap = 1 heap.

Comment: @Paul I agree that the definition of addition is at least as important as the definition of "heap of sand". I made a small update to the answer.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what conbination means at this point, but am I correct to say that 1 heap  + 1 heap "combines" to 1 heap?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is a misunderstanding of the words involved. One number plus one number is still one number; the numbers involved are not the same, but they're all numbers. Similarly, one heap of sand plus one heap of sand is another, completely different heap of sand. Being "a heap of sand" is a property, not an identifier. If you said "heap of sand A plus heap of sand A is heap of sand A", I would say no, that's false - adding "heap of sand A" to itself should duplicate each grain of sand, resulting in heap of sand B which is twice as large.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the paradox by stating "Addition does not preserve the number of heaps".

Answer (score 0):

Linguistically speaking, sand is a [mass noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) like milk and money.

> a noun with the syntactic property that any quantity of it is treated as an undifferentiated unit ...
>    In English, mass nouns are characterized by the fact that they cannot be directly modified by a numeral without specifying a unit of measurement, and that they cannot combine with an indefinite article (a or an). ...
>
> **Cumulativity and mass nouns**
>
> An expression P has  [cumulative reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulativity)  if and only if for any X and Y:
>
> If X can be described as P and Y can be described as P, as well, then the sum of X and Y can also be described as P.